# What does "Hollaback Girl" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Gwen Stefani says, "I ain't no hollaback girl" in her song. What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia has [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollaback_Girl):

> Because Stefani never disclosed the song title's meaning, reviewers came up with various interpretations. In a satirical, line-by-line analysis of the song's lyrics, *OC Weekly* critic Greg Stacy humorously speculated that "Gwen is apparently the captain of the cheerleader squad; she is the girl who 'hollas' the chants, not one of the girls who simply 'hollas' them back".<sup>[[6]](http://www.ocweekly.com/2005-05-05/music/this-shit-is-bananas/)</sup> The most commonly accepted meaning is that a hollaback girl responds to a confrontation with words but that Stefani would rather take initiative and "step it up". However, the term can be traced to American construction workers of the 1940s used to denigrate females that would positively respond to their "catcalls" or hollers.<sup>[[7]](http://www.nationalreview.com/articles/215282/b-n-n-s/peter-wood)</sup>